# Invalid Argument exception in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exception, testing, automated-tests, invalid-argument

I created a method for photoUpload

```
public void uploadPhoto() {
              
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", wePhotoInput);
            
wePhotoInput.click();

               
    String filePath = "C:/Users/katar/Desktop/featured-pic-1.jpg";

              
    wePhotoInput.sendKeys(filePath);
}
```

And this is the test for it

```
@Test
public void tc21UploadPhoto () {
    Formpage.openPage();
    Formpage.uploadPhoto();
    
}
```

And I keep getting `InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument`

Here is the complete trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.124)
Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [05600440e09d8e34d22964322e262fbd, clickElement {id=61D020F06CE56DCA84C566D11331017B_element_60}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 119.0.6045.124, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 119.0.6045.105 (38c72552c5e..., userDataDir: C:\Users\katar\AppData\Loca...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56975}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:56975/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 119.0.6045.124, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (05600440e09d8e34d22964322e262fbd)] -> xpath: //div[@class='form-group']//child::input[@name='photo']]
Session ID: 05600440e09d8e34d22964322e262fbd
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy18.click(Unknown Source)
    at cubes.webpages.posts.PostFormPage.uploadPhoto(PostFormPage.java:113)
    at cubes.test.TestAddPost.tc21UploadPhoto(TestAddPost.java:252)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

When I run the test, it scrolls to the photo upload field, but doesn't click on it, just stops and shows the exception. It doesn't say that the element is not clickable, or that the xpath is wrong, that's why I don't understand why is it not working

Comment: click will throw "invalid argument" if the input is of type="file" methinks.... from the W3C spec: If the element is an input element in the file upload state return error with error code invalid argument.  (remove the click... it's shouldn't be needed)